# Приведение типа к dynamic

Tags: c#

```
  dynamic instance = new Program();
```

- Это будет UpCust или DownCast?

Или как я догадываюсь - когда во время выполнения тип переменной instance будет меняться, то это будет динамическое приведение типов? -Т.е динамически в зависимости от того что в dynamic по ходу выполнения программы будет происходить то UpCust то DownCast?

UPD:

```
dynamic instance = new A;
```

.Хорошо, возьмем не Program и dynamic, а два класса А и Б и если Б дочерний от А и на строке 
и если вместо типа dynamic -тип будет тот же что и справа - то привидения не будет, не если в прцесе выполнения вместо dynamic будет например тип B, то это будет DownCast. Вот в чем моя мысль. просто может я не очень удачно взял пример кода с Program - т.к его не к чему приводить, **поэтому для данного конкретного случая**

```
 dynamic instance = new Program();
```

Подсказали здравую мысль - У переменной instance будет фактический тип правой части присваивания, приведения типов там не будет.
- но если взять шире, абстрактнее - то вот в чем мой вопрос?

Т.е ВОПРОС ПО ПРЕЖНЕМУ В ЦЕЛОМ ОСТАЕТСЯ ОТКРЫТЫМ.

Comment: Хм, а хороший вопрос. Думаю, что это вовсе не cast, но не уверен.

Comment: С одной стороны, под капотом `dynamic` — это `object`, так что похоже на upcast. С другой стороны, можно вызывать методы рантайм-типа, так что по функциональности похоже на downcast.

Comment: @VladD, Ну не, там же вообще каста ж нету, и все через run-time

Comment: @Grundy: А в чём разница? У нас есть формальное определение upcast'а?

Comment: Почему каста нет?

Comment: @VladD, а есть?

Comment: @Grundy: Ну должно где-то быть же :)

Comment: @Grundy - UpCast -Это привидение экземпляров дочерних классов к классу родительскому. Вот и определение. DownCast -наоборот

Comment: Т.е если класс А - родительский а, класс Б - дочерний, то привидение от Б к А - это UpCast, от А к Б - DownCast

Comment: Спасибо, гляну!

Comment: Ещё один аргумент за upcast — это то, что любой тип можно привести к `dynamic`, и `is dynamic` возвращает `true` http://ideone.com/EreELs

Comment: @VladD, вот только dynamic - Не дочерний и не родительский

Comment: @Grundy: Почему? Ссылки на рефлексию не принимаются :)

Comment: @VladD, например ни в одной классе не прописано: `:dynamic` :)

Comment: У [ExpandoObject](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/7c6c0201b7e406f9347706a17e8c62b08a715d81#diff-8f686ae70032367687f67faf4b8eae56) видимо нет каста вообще, просто замена объекта класса.

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, в моём примере `class Program : object` тоже явно не прописано. Но `Program` ведь несмотря на это подкласс `object`. Так что не доказывает.

Comment: @VladD на самом деле не совсем любой тип можно привести к `dynamic`. Например экземпляры `TypedReference` - нельзя.

Comment: @Nikita: И наверное указатели (те, которые в unsafe-коде) тоже.

Comment: @VladislavKhapin причем тут вообще ExpandoObject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тип `dynamic` является особым типом, не совпадающим с типом `object`. Он не является классом, и поэтому не участвует в иерархиях наследования: произвести класс от `dynamic` нельзя. Я не смог найти его непосредственный базовый тип в спецификации, но его базовым типом как минимум является `object`.

Это означает, что конверсия из `dynamic` в другие типы и обратно не может являться ни up-, ни downcast'ом (за исключением типа `object`).

Какая же конверсия происходит при присвоении между `dynamic` и другими типами? Ответ на это можно найти в спецификации языка: это специальные *динамические* конверсии, описанные в разделах 6.1.8 (неявная, из другого типа в `dynamic`), и 6.2.6 (явная, из `dynamic` в другой тип).

Итак, ответ: это специальные динамические конверсии, не являющиеся ни up-, ни downcast'ом.

Comment: За исключением `object` - почему? И откуда у синтаксического сахара вообще имеется базовый тип?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: согласно спецификации, `dynamic` — тип. То, что он в CLR не получил отдельного CLR-типа, это подробность имплементации.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: а `object`, согласно той же спецификации, базовый тип _любого_ другого типа.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Можно ссылочки на эти разделы?

Comment: @BadCats Спецификацию языка можно скачать или найти в папке со студией, подробности тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx

Comment: @BadCats Онлайн-версию лично я не видел.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Кстати, интересно, что `object` базовый тип даже is unsafe-указателей. Это мне как-то не осень нравится. С другой стороны, между ними вроде бы нету конверсии, так что может быть не так уж всё плохо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov она есть вот [тут](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/README.md)